# $password with ssh chpasswd

Tags: ssh, password, sudo, php

I've a problem with **"ssh chpasswd"** .. I need to implement the **"$password"** of register..
Eg.. I've this code..

```
echo $ssh->exec("sudo sh -c 'echo $user:test | chpasswd'");
```

When the script is executed, the **"$user"** of register is created and the **password "test"** also too.. but this password I need to write on the code, and I don't want this.. I want to implement the **"$password"** of user register.. eg..

```
echo $ssh->exec("sudo sh -c 'echo $user:$password | chpasswd'");
```

---

Now I tried this mode

```
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$salt = hash('sha512', $username); //Salt
$password_hash = hash('sha512', $salt.$password);
$password_hash = $_SESSION['password'];
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE `password`= '$password_hash'");

// ... 

echo $ssh->exec("sudo sh -c 'echo $user:$password_hash | chpasswd'");
```

but the code is apparently ok.. but doesn't work..
and I tried put this:

```
$cmd = sprintf( "sudo sh -c 'echo %s:%s | chpasswd'", $user, $password );
var_dump( $cmd );
echo $ssh->exec( $cmd );
```

but doesn't show me the command to be executed..

I am not able to do this command works.. doesn't create the password when the user register on the website..

Can help me guys.. ?

Regards..